# How disable base64 storing for ingest-attachment elasticsearch plugin?

Tags: elasticsearch, indexing, full-text-search, full-text-indexing, data-ingestion

The [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/plugins/master/using-ingest-attachment.html) shows example about how store base64 documents into elasticsearch via ingest-attachment plugin. But after this I got that elasticsearch index contains parsed text and base64 field source. Why does it needed? Is there a way to remove base64 text field and keep only text after document was indexed not it content?

Answer (score 3):

There's not option for that, but you can add a "remove" processor to your ingestion pipeline:

```
PUT _ingest/pipeline/attachment
{
    "description": "Extract attachment information and remove the source encoded data",
    "processors": [
        {
            "attachment": {
                "field": "data",
                "properties": [
                    "content",
                    "content_type",
                    "content_length"
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "remove": {
                "field": "data"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```